# jQuery slidedown menu on mouse over

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  

        $("#flip").hover(function()
        {
            $("#panel").slideToggle();

        });
    });
</script>


<li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#s3"><div id="flip">programmes</div></a><div id="panel"><a href="#s1">urvashi</a></div></li>
```

It's a sliding menu. It slides down when I click programes.but when I try to click options or submenu inside it, it slides up.I want it to stay for all submenus. Please help

Answer (score 1):

change the function .hover() to .mouseenter()

Comment: i even want the #panel to slideup when i leave the #flip. but also DONT want to slideUp the "#panel" when i'm in #panel (when i'm leaving #flip). inshort i want the menu to stay even when i hover.